# DHT11 Temprature sensor makes raspberry pi go crazy!

Tags: gpio, sensor

I am trying to use the DHT11 sensor temprature and humidity sensor with my Raspberry Pi 4B. When I connect the sensor with my Raspberry Pi and turn it on, the red LED on it starts blinking and it can't boot! I searched and found that it indicates that the power supply is messed up but I am using the official power supply! Also, I know that the Pi is not broken because it is working with the 2 channel relay and LEDs I have! This happens every time I connect the DHT11 sensor!  [image: This is the DHT11 temprature sensor I am using with my raspberry pi 4b] [![The connections][2]][2]

[image: My connections![![][3]][3]]

Also, I tried wiring it again and it got heated up!
How can I get it to work?

[image: Closeup of my connections!]

Comment: With your Pi turned off post a photo of how it is wired.

Comment: Yes, so I have heard that DHT11 is frying Rpi's every now and then:(1) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/99173/only-a-solid-red-light-and-no-ethernet-lights-after-broken-script

(2) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97949/circuit-wiring-issue

(3) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96560/dht11-sensor-and-the-wrong-voltage-may-have-fried-my-rpi3

(4) https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/102234/gpio-pin-turns-off-immediately-when-switch-is-connected-turns-back-on-when-disc

Comment: Welcome -- but you need to include a photograph of the DHT11 attached to the Pi or else there is not much anyone can say.

Comment: Include a photograph of how you have wired it *with the power off* if you don't want to turn it on.

Comment: Okay, I will add a photo. I have to find my webcam!

Comment: Okay, I have added the required photos! Please take a look and troubleshoot my issue!

Comment: Wrong wiring !! See:
https://joy-it.net/files/files/Produkte/SEN-KY015TF/SEN-KY015-Manual.pdf
Succes !

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** have a DHT11, you have a module with a DHT11 and a resistor on it.

There are several variants of these with different pinouts.
Unless these are labelled, you need to figure out which pin on the connector goes to which pin on the DHT11.

On my module the center pin is the V+ and the left the Data. (Yours looks similar, although the use a a Red wire for data is confusing and should be avoided!)

**However** you have connected yours to **5V** and have thus applied 5V to a GPIO pin, which may have damaged the GPIO or the Pi itself.

The table in your original question (now deleted) showed connection should be to pin 1 3.3V. You also appear to be using a different GPIO connection to that listed.

**Never** connect any 5V source to the GPIO!

Comment: The PI is 5v tolerant IIRC