# DHT 11 Sensor Voltages

Tags: gpio

## GOAL

A 3-Wire DHT 11 of unknown pedigree is to be connected to a Raspberry Pi:

[image]

[SDA GPIO](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/i2c#)

The goal is to take "due diligence" and avoid frying an rPi.  Thank you

## RESOURCES

Ada Fruit's [4-pin DHT11](https://www.adafruit.com/product/386) indicates 3-5 Power.

The "[kookeye" tutorial](http://kookye.com/2017/06/01/how-to-set-up-temperature-and-humidity-sensor-dht11-on-raspberry-pi-2/) shows 3.3V power & 3 direct wires between DHT11 and rPi.

[image]

## QUESTIONS

1. If powered by 5V, will the DHT11 communicate at proper (3.3V?) voltage level?
2. If powered by 3.3V will the DHT11 communicate at the proper 3.3V voltage level?

Comment: Why take the risk?  Why not just power it from 3V3?

Comment: I DEFINITELY wouldn't! These modules have a pullup from Vcc to the data pin.

Comment: My answer to the following DHT11 question might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97949/circuit-wiring-issue.

Comment: Yet another of my couple of answers on DHT11, this time explaining the "latch up" thing which might have fired your Pi: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96560/dht11-sensor-and-the-wrong-voltage-may-have-fried-my-rpi3. Good luck.  Cheeers..

Comment: @tlfong01:  Good postings! I have not wired the sensor: my rPi should be in good shape.  I added a new questions based on tlfong01's comments.  I am now wondering if powered by 3.3.V the DHT11 will safely communicate at 3.3V with the data line?

Comment: @gatorback: Killing Pi softly with Dht11: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oKOtzIo-uYw. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

***Answer***

*DHT11 Wiring Suggestion*

[image: dht11 wiring]

---

***References***

(1) [Rpi connected to MCP3008 connected to DHT11 seemed fried problem - Asked 2019apr15 Viewed 115 times](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/97949/rpi-connected-to-mcp3008-connected-to-dht11-seemed-fried-problem)

(2) [DHT11 sensor and the wrong voltage may have fried my RPi3 - Asked 2019apr26 Viewed 145 times](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/96560/dht11-sensor-and-the-wrong-voltage-may-have-fried-my-rpi3)

---

***Appendices***

---